# Metaclass configure. Python version conflict

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributes, python-3.4, metaclass

```
class UpperAttrMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs["b"] = 77
        return super(UpperAttrMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class Cls(object):
     __metaclass__ = UpperAttrMetaclass

f = Cls()
print(f.b)
```

I tried to run this code on Python 3.4.3 and 2.7.11.
In 2.7.11 it works well(output - `77`), but 3.4.3 throw *Attribute Error*

Here is the output (3.4.3)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/LABS/BSUIR_labs/4cem/PYTHON/lab2/meta.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(f.b)
AttributeError: 'Cls' object has no attribute 'b'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I fix this? metaclasses works in different way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python3, you declare the metaclass inline:

```
class Cls(object, metaclass=UpperAttrMetaclass):
    ...
```

I think that `2to3` should handle this, but if you need to support both in the same source file without using `2to3`, then you'll probably want some sort of shimming library.  `six` is the de-facto standard here.  You'll want to use [`six.with_metaclass`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.with_metaclass):

```
import six
class Cls(six.with_metaclass(UpperAttrMetaclass, object)):
    ...
```